# enabling multiple RDP in python

Tags: python, command-line, command, rdp

I would like to start up to 40 remote sessions to different computers

I used the following code, I get a problem in that the command line is stuck with teh first remote session and does not allow the next set of command to go thought,

```
import os

def first_connection():
    os.system('cmdkey /generic:192.168.1.101 /user:Username /pass:Password')
    os.system('mstsc /v:192.168.1.101)'

def second_connection():
    os.system('cmdkey /generic:192.168.1.102 /user:Username /pass:Password')
    os.system('mstsc /v:192.168.1.101)'

first connection()
second_connection()
```

Comment: `os.system` is a blocking call. Your code is inside `first_connection()` as long as that RDP session is active. You could either use `subprocess.Popen` or threads to start multiple sessions in parallel (or use the windows command `start`).

Comment: Thank you the following worked:                                                                  start /min mstsc /v:"%Server%"

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` is a blocking call. Your code is inside `first_connection()` as long as that RDP session is active. You could either use `subprocess.Popen` or threads to start multiple sessions in parallel (or use the windows command `start`).